# How was Srirangam Ranganathaswamy temple wall constructed?

Tags: temple, vaishnavism, alwar, ranganatha

The task was assigned to Thurumangai alwar who was then a king turned to thief. He constructed the temple wall by acquiring a gold Buddha idol from srilanka.

Anyone knows the story how he brought the golden idol from heavy security and in which scripture mentioned?

Comment: Thirumangai Alwar didn't build the Sri Rangam temple itself, the temple already existed but he built one of the walls around the temple.  He paid for the wall using the gold from the golden Buddha statue.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan--I agree. He has built the surrounding walls  [Mathil]for the temple. How he brought the golden Buddha statue under strict security measures?